# How to check if Link is offline or broken with Android Webview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I use an Android Webview to load a URL like this:

```
mWebView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

mWebView.loadUrl("someUrl");
```

**How can I detect if the link the webView should load is offline or broken?**

Comment: Could you please post an example?

Comment: I was updated my ans, Check it once.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do detect broken links in WebView using `onRecicedError()` in WebViewClient Class.

You have to create an object for WebViewClient and implement onRecicedError() method and set WebViewClient  Object using `setWebViewClient()` method in WebView

**Eg:**

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
      if(errorCode == 404){
             Log.d("Webview", "Invalid URL: "+url);
      }
      else if(errorCode == 500){
           Log.d("Webview", "Internal Server error: "+url);
      }
  }

  @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
  @Override
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
    // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
    onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
  }
});
```

Comment: @confile Let me know any doubts in my ans.

Comment: How do I check the status code if it is something like 404?

Comment: @confile Using onReciceive() 2nd Argument errorCode,

Comment: Could you please add this to your answer.

Comment: @confile Updated my ans. Check if  it solved then mark it solved.

Comment: Well I do not get an error when I get a 404 and a redirect. Check out this link: https://buchung.salonmeister.de/place/#offer-details-page?id=907523423499&venueId=301655234234

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93364/discussion-between-jitendra-kumar-balla-and-confile).